# Storing (caching) Google map with given radius and using it while offline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

First of all if this one is a duplicate, please refer me to the original thread(s), as I have failed to find the exact thing I was searching for.

Basically for some time now I am developing an application for the client and it was all going well up until this point.

The client requests to be able to

**I) While online:**

1. Access Google map
2. Set the point by clicking on map
3. Store a portion of the map around the above mentioned point locally as per the radius he/she selected (eg. 3km)

**II) While offline:**

1. Access the map he stored in above steps.
2. The application should draw the path as he moves as per GPS coords received from another device via BT.
3. The ability to zoom in/out, scroll around map and everything else that standard google map allows.

I am completely lost on this one and would like at least someone to point out the right direction for something like this.

I'm well aware how to handle most of the above while Android device is online, but have no idea how to do this while offline.

I pretty much need help with I-3, II-1, and maybe II-3.

PS. I don't really need BT tutorials and guidance (mentioned in II-2), that part is handled, I just pointed out the source of coords.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider.html). The TileProvider provides the images that are used in the tile overlay. You should be able to save portion of map and create your own tileprovider and access tiles locally.

Comment: Well, I kinda found all I need in relation to TitleProvider, but I still do not see how to cache **Google's tiles** with it. All guides I have found provided options to cache alternative maps. My client claims that few of their competitor's managed to cache tiles from **Google**'s own maps. So basically client insists for it to be **Google's tiles**.